# How to make a stopwatch console?

Tags: c#, console-application

I was thinking of doing:

```
int intCount = 0;
int intConstant = ...;

while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(intCount / intConstant + " seconds");
}
```

But I don't know how to figure out the constant to make the stopwatch count in seconds.

Comment: There's a class for that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: There are several `Timer` classes in the BCL. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx - old but still relevant.

Comment: You won't be able to use a constant because the loop won't always run at the same speed.

Comment: Consider that `intConstant` isn't going to be the same value each time. It would be larger or smaller depending on how fast the CPU is, among other things. Hence, the timer classes that the other folks mentioned. These classes provide timing that is more or less independent of computer clock speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a loop, this will be processor specific. Better use the `StopWatch` class:

```
var watch = StopWatch.StartNew();

while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000f + " seconds");
}
```

Comment: why do you divide by 1000f instead of just 1000?

Comment: @RedAces: if you divide by 1000, you will get a rounded integer. Dividing by 1000f will give you a floating point number which is more precise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use StopWatch class in the [System.Diagnostics namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

```
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess at what you want, do :

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 + " seconds");
}
```